# CMake, multiple targets (asan tsan..) without having to recompile everything

Tags: cmake, target

**Goal**
I want to define several targets:

- make msan: compiles the code with clang with memory sanitizer
- make tsan: compiles the code with clang with thread sanitizer
- make     : compiles the code with gcc

And be able to easily switch between them.
For example I don't want each time I switch rebuild all my objects, (I will have to do it the first time of course, but later if I modify a file and I do make and then make asan it should recompile only this file for each target)

**What I have done so far**

I have managed to create these targets and from the root directory, but each time I have to do a make clean and recompile.

```
option(CLANG_MSAN "Enable Clang memory sanitizer" OFF)
if (CLANG_MSAN)
    set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer")
endif()

add_custom_target(asan
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
    -DCLANG_MSAN=ON
    -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++
    -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang)
```

Is it possible to do such a thing with CMake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but use multiple build directories:

- Create a build directory per configuration.
- Configure your project in your build directories with the parameters you need. E.g. `cmake -DCMAKE_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-fsanitize=thread" ..` or the stuff from your question.
- If you switch the build directory, you changed your setup.

This implies out-of-source builds, which are encouraged by CMake anyway.

Comment: My sources are in src. I have now 2 build directory msan/ tsan/. In it the makefiles are generated. But there are no longer makefiles created in src/ this means that I should first go in the build directory and then compile?

Comment: @moeryn CMake has an emphasis on out-of-source builds. This is very useful to avoid polluting the source directory with temporary and output files that might find themselves accidentally added to source control. Also it allows exactly this, have separate build configurations existing in parallel.

Comment: @SirDarius So there is no way to call a simple make from the source code directory?

Comment: @moeryn CMake discourages in-source builds, it is even stated in the FAQ (https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Out-of-source_build_trees). You could pretty much create a `build.sh` script located in your source directory that invokes make for every build directory.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be able to achieve this with the [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/module/ExternalProject.html) module. You could add three external projects, one for `msan`, one for `tsan`, and one for the basic GCC build. The two sanitiser builds would be marked as `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL 1`.

The CMakeLists for all three of them could share the common part via `include()`.

Something like this:

**Root CMakeLists.txt**

```
ExternalProject_Add(msan
  EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL 1
  SOURCE_DIR msan
  CMAKE_GENERATOR ...
)

ExternalProject_Add(tsan
  EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL 1
  SOURCE_DIR tsan
  CMAKE_GENERATOR ...
)

ExternalProject_Add(normal
  SOURCE_DIR src
  CMAKE_GENERATOR ...
)
```

**src/CMakeLists.txt**

```
include(common.cmake)
```

**src/common.cmake**

```
# Normal CMake code for your project
add_library(...)
```

**msan/CMakeLists.txt**

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer")

include(../src/common.cmake)
```